# Latent Dirichlet Allocation: Newton-Raphson method

Tags: derivatives, partial-derivative, newton-raphson

I am trying to understand one step in the Newton-Raphson method, used in [the paper](https://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume3/blei03a/blei03a.pdf) on LDA by Blei, Ng and Jordan. Namely, how does taking the derivative of $L$, w.r.t. $\alpha_j$ result in this equation. Also, what exactly is $\delta(i,j)$?

> The terms which contain $\alpha$ are:
>
> $$ L_{[\alpha]} =  \sum_{d=1}^{M} \bigg(  \log\Gamma(\sum_{j=1}^k \alpha_j ) - \sum_{i=1}^{k} \log \Gamma(\alpha_i)  + \sum_{i=1}^{k}((\alpha_i-1)( \Psi(\gamma_{d_i}) - \Psi\sum_{j=1}^{k} \gamma_{d_j}))) \bigg)$$
> Taking the derivative with respect to $\alpha_i$ gives:
> $$\frac{\partial L}{\partial \alpha_i} = M ( \Psi( \sum_{j=1}^{k} \alpha_j) - \Psi (\alpha_i)) + \sum_{d=1}^{M}( \Psi(\gamma_{d_i}) - \Psi(\sum_{j=1}^{k} \gamma_{d_j}))$$
> The derivative depends on $\alpha_j$ where $j \neq i$, and we therefore must use and iterative method to find the maximal $\alpha$. In particular, the Hessian is in the form found in Eq. (10):
> $$  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \alpha_i \alpha_j} = \delta(ij)M \Psi'(\alpha_i) - \Psi'(\sum_{j=1}^{k} \alpha_j)$$

Comment: Can you put the equation in LaTeX?

Comment: [Kronecker delta](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kronecker_delta)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like there is some typo in the paper. The actual Hessian should be of the form:

> $$  \frac{\partial L}{\partial \alpha_i \alpha_j} = M(\Psi'(\sum_{j=1}^{k} \alpha_j)-\delta(ij) \Psi'(\alpha_i))$$

Note the difference.

- Here, "M" is multiplied by both the terms instead of just one term.
- The signs are reversed.